# How do I add to the existing JSON data as new insert/append or updates to existing json data

Tags: json, postgresql-9.5

I have a jsonb column to which I will add data all at one time, or add data incrementally at various points in time or update existing name-value pairs.

One such case is explained below. Let me know how to app the second user_profile after the first is added. I am not sure if the user_profile format itself needs to be modified. I tried inserting 2 profiles in a single insert and was able to retrieve data according to my needs. So I believe the design format of JSON is ok.

```
create table myjsontab (jsonb_details jsonb);
```

insert first profile_type data:

```
insert into myjsontab(jsonb_details) 
values (
'{"user_profile":{
    "customer":{
        "profile_name":"customer",
        "user_status":"NEW","user_state":"pending",
         "s3url":["file1","abc/1/clients/51/clients/acmepmwallet1/"]
         }
}}'
);
```

----------------- works.

Insert two profile_type data in one insert

```
insert into myjsontab(jsonb_details) 
values (
'{"user_profile":{
    "customer":{
        "profile_name":"customer",
        "user_status":"NEW","user_state":"pending",
         "s3url":["file1","abc/1/clients/51/clients/acmepm1/"]
         },
       "admin staff":{
        "profile_name":"admin staff",
        "user_status":"NEW","user_state":"admin upload",
         "s3url":"abc/"
         }
}}'
);
```

----------------- also works.

but I am looking to see how I can insert the second profile ("admin staff") set as an "update" or "addition at a later time".

If I try `update <table_name> set json_details= json_details|| 'new dataset'` there are many issues with formatting the data. I think this approach is wrong.

I am not sure if jsonb_set is a good option to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
update users set user_details=jsonb_set_lax(user_details->'user_profile','{user_profile,2}','{
    "profile_name":"corporate staff",
    }',true)
```

This seems to have worked to solve my issue. Posting this if someone comes here looking for similar answers...

The point to note is the '{user_profile,2}' index. Since I have 2 items in my array, I have to "INSERT" this as the 3rd item which in array parlance is position 2. Since arrays start from 0.

So in your case, you have to find the jsonb_array_length and use that index number as the entry point.